# Rewrite URL from subdomain to folder structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL from sub domain to folder structure, like: sub.example.com to example.com which i had done successfully. now i want to add a rewrite rule which will convert URL like, https://www.sub.example.com to https://www.example.com/sub.

Currently i have added following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: redirecting URL from https://www.sub.example.com to https://www.example.com/sub is not working, but https://sub.example.com to https://example.com/sub is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^/]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R,L]
```